# Strange behaviour of Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

MMA version 13.3

Can somebody explain the following behavior:

Here Simplify works as expected:

```
x1 e[1] + x2 e[1]  // Simplify

(x1 + x2) e[1]
```

However, here Simplify only works on e[2]

```
x1 e[1] + x2 e[1] + x3 e[2] + x4  e[2] // Simplify

x1 e[1] + x2 e[1] + (x3 + x4) e[2]
```

And here Simplify does not work at all:

```
x1  e[1] + x2  e[1] + x3 e[2] + x4 e[2] + x5 e[3] + x6 e[3] // Simplify

x1 e[1] + x2 e[1] + x3 e[2] + x4 e[2] + x5 e[3] + x6 e[3]
```

FullSimplify does not have these problems.

Comment: `Simplify` wants to distinguish itself from `FullSimplify` otherwise it could lose its job in Mathematica.

Comment: Just to save other folks the work:  For the second expression, `Simplify` reduces the `LeafCount` from 17 to 15, while `FullSimplify` reduces it to 13.  For the third expression `Simplify` doesn't change the `LeafCount` at all (obviously), while `FullSimplify` reduces it from 25 to 19.

Comment: Somewhat speculatively: the number of possible transformations is subject to combinatorial explosion.  Mathematica presumably uses various heuristics as to which transformations to attempt.  As expressions grow in size, fewer types of transformation can be attempted (to avoid run-time explosion).  Presumably it would be difficult to identify the types of symmetry that seem so natural to us.

Comment: @mikado  You could be correct for more complicated expressions. However, with 4 terms there is hardly a combinatoric explosion.

Comment: @DanielHuber you are probably right, but does simplification know it is working with a "top-level" expression?  Or does it do the same thing when attempting simplification of a subexpression of something more complicated?