# How to factorize $x+y$ in this kind of example?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, factorization

Consider the following simple polynomial in two variables `5 + 2x + 2y`. Suppose I want to simplify it to `5+2(x+y)`. I have no idea how Mathematica can do that. Both `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` don't work. I tried also to use `Factor` and `FactorTerms` but it also doesn't work.

To give some context, the reason I'm interest in this is that I'm simplifying some complicated expressions and in them often things of the schematic form `a + b x + b y`  appear, and I need to be able to factor this as `a+b(x+y)`because `x+y` can be simplified.

Comment: Similar question but also without answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291944/strange-behaviour-of-simplify

Comment: That's interesting, but in that case `FullSimplify` seems to solve the issue, but here for some reason it does not. Also, I just checked and the LeafCount of `2x+2y+5` is 8 while that of `2(x+y)+5` is 7, so `FullSimplify` in principle should do this factorization, no?

Comment: A funny example `exp = 5 + 10^10 Total@ToExpression@Alphabet[];
exp // Expand // FullSimplify`

Comment: FullSimplify[5+2(x+y)]  does not change anything, too, irrespective to the settings of ComplexityFunction

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to replace the number with a variable of a name that you do not use elsewhere.

```
FullSimplify[5 + 2 x + 2 y /. (#)] /. Reverse@# &@(2 -> fu)

exp = 5 + 10^10 Total@ToExpression@Alphabet[] // Expand
FullSimplify[exp /. (#)] /. Reverse@# &@(10^10 -> fu)
```

---

```
5 + 2 (x + y)

5 + 10000000000 a + 10000000000 b + 10000000000 c + 
 10000000000 d + 10000000000 e + 10000000000 f + 10000000000 g + 
 10000000000 h + 10000000000 i + 10000000000 j + 10000000000 k + 
 10000000000 l + 10000000000 m + 10000000000 n + 10000000000 o + 
 10000000000 p + 10000000000 q + 10000000000 r + 10000000000 s + 
 10000000000 t + 10000000000 u + 10000000000 v + 10000000000 w + 
 10000000000 x + 10000000000 y + 10000000000 z

5 + 
 10000000000 (a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + 
    o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
xfactor = (GatherBy[List @@ #, NumericQ] // Map[Apply[Head@#]] // 
      Map[Simplify] // Apply[Head[#]]) &;

expr = 5 + 2 x + 2 y;
xfactor@expr

expr = a + b x + 5 + c y + 6 x + d y;
xfactor@expr

expr = 5 + 10000000000 a + 10000000000 b + 10000000000 c + 
  10000000000 d + 10000000000 e + 10000000000 f + 10000000000 g + 
  10000000000 h + 10000000000 i + 10000000000 j + 10000000000 k + 
  10000000000 l + 10000000000 m + 10000000000 n + 10000000000 o + 
  10000000000 p + 10000000000 q + 10000000000 r + 10000000000 s + 
  10000000000 t + 20000000000 u + 20000000000 v + 10000000000 w + 
  10000000000 x + 10000000000 y + 10000000000 z
xfactor@expr
```

Comment: (+1) Nice, @Syed! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
xfactor = Total@Values[GroupBy[List @@ #, NumericQ, Simplify@Total@# &]] &;
expr = 5 + 2 x + 2 y;

xfactor@expr

5 + 2 (x + y)

expr = 5 + 10000000000 a + 10000000000 b + 10000000000 c + 
  10000000000 d + 10000000000 e + 10000000000 f + 10000000000 g + 
  10000000000 h + 10000000000 i + 10000000000 j + 10000000000 k + 
  10000000000 l + 10000000000 m + 10000000000 n + 10000000000 o + 
  10000000000 p + 10000000000 q + 10000000000 r + 10000000000 s + 
  10000000000 t + 20000000000 u + 20000000000 v + 10000000000 w + 
  10000000000 x + 10000000000 y + 10000000000 z;

xfactor@expr

5 + 10000000000 (a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + 
n + o + p + q + r + s + t + 2 u + 2 v + w + x + y + z)
```